# Xrandr detects but doesn't connect HDMI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hdmi

So, I'm trying to connect NES mini by HDMI port to my laptop running on linux mint 20. I am using `$ xrandr --output HDMI-1` but it seems it doesn't have any effect. Console just gives no output as if everything worked but running `xrandr` still shows that HDMI-1 is disconnected. How do I show HDMI input on the screen then?

```
$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Uh, isn't the NES mini a game console that wants to be hooked up to a screen? Or does thing actually have a screen built in and is able to display external video?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be hooked up to a screen but does that mean it couldn't be connected to a laptop and then display content on its screen?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to use your laptop as a *display* for your game console? If so, I'm sorry that I have to tell you that the HDMI ports on graphics cards (and laptops) are *outputs*. Those can't receive video, because the circuit simply isn't made for that. It would be really nice if that was possible. But to ingest HDMI into a computer you'll need a special HDMI capture device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI ports on graphics cards and laptops are strictly output ports. They can only transmit. They are physically incapable to receive video.

It would be really nice, and a selling features, if there were laptops and/or graphics cards with HDMI ports that are bidirectional. However such *does not exist!*